# Avoid cluttering the tensorflow graph with assign operations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to run something like the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.Variable(42.)

for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(x.assign(42.))
    sess.run(x)
    print(i)
```

several times. The actual code is much more complicated and uses more variables.
The problem is that the TensorFlow graph grows with each instantiated assign op, which makes the graph grow, eventually slowing down the computation.

I could use `feed_dict=` to set the value, but I would like to keep my state in the graph, so that I can easily query it in other places.

Is there some way of avoiding cluttering the current graph in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found a good solution for this:
I define a placeholder `y` and create an op that assigns the value of `y` to `x`.
I can then use that op repeatedly, using `feed_dict={y: value}` to assign a new value to x.
This doesn't add another op to the graph.
It turns out that the loop runs *much* more quickly than before as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.Variable(42.)
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

assign = x.assign(y)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(assign, feed_dict={y: i})
    print(i, sess.run(x))
```

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a better way to do things. One thing we try to do in example code is to define the entire graph before creating the `tf.Session`—or as close to that as possible—so that problems like this don't arise.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `sess.run(x.assign(42.))`
two things happen: (i) a new `assign` operation is added to the computational graph `sess.graph`, (ii) the newly added operation executes. No wonder the graph gets pretty large if loop repeats many times. If you define assignment operation before execution (`asgnmnt_operation` in example below), just a single operation is added to the graph so the performance is great:

```
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.Variable(42.)
c = tf.constant(42.)
asgnmnt_operation = x.assign(c) 
sess = tf.Session()

for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(asgnmnt_operation) 
    sess.run(x)
    print(i)
```